# How to restore objects in s3 using pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to restore object which is in the glacier in s3 using Pyspark.
After searching about it, I found that the code below works for my case, converting object from glacier to the standard class in s3.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

bucket = 'bucket_name'
key = 'object_name'
response = s3.restore_object(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=key,
    RestoreRequest={
        'Days': 1,
        'GlacierJobParameters': {
            'Tier': 'Standard',
        },
    },
)
```

However, what I want to achieve is using the `pyspark` code but not the `python` code.
As you can see it, the code above is only pure python code which is working on the single node. I tried to look for the way to restore object using `pyspark` or the spark apis but failed because I cannot see any documents about it.

So I think that there is no way to restore or other aws sdk apis using pyspark directly.

It is my assumption so I am not sure.

So my question is that is there any way to restore object using `pyspark` not the pure python?

Comment: pyspark is python+spark. so, when you say you want to achieve it in pyspark, think about what you want to achieve with spark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AWS v1 Java SDK which is on the classpath if you have the Apache Hadoop S3A filesystem connector. (Amazon EMR is not covered by this answer)

Once you have (at the spark/java level) an instance of S3AFileSystem (left as an exercise...). you can call `getAmazonS3ClientForTesting("my excuse here")` and get the instantiated/configured s3 client connection to talk to that bucket.

*warning, that method will be removed once the s3a connector moves to the AWS V2 SDK*

Anyway, given the connector you can create the relevant requests (aws sdk docs) and submit to s3.

Adding a real way to work with the data has been considered in [HADOOP-14837](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14837). As of April 2023, nobody is working on that -this could be your opportunity to contribute to the codebase. This would be welcome provided you target hadoop trunk (v2 SDK) and put as much effort into writing the tests as the production code. It is often actually harder to do them, but more fun.